# Converting decimal degrees units to km in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I am trying to figure out how I can transform my unit of length from decimal degree to km when I import the following simple ArcGIS polygon shape.  Ultimately, I would like to have this information available when I assign this spatial polygon to my window in spatstat [i.e., Window area = xx square unit & Unit of length: xx km].

I did came across this post: [R-sig-geo](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/readOGR-default-unit-td7337370.html)

This is what I've done so far, but I don't understand why/if I need to do so. Doesn't my div0A SpatialPolygonsDataFrame already has my CRS argument defined? Why do I need to spTransform then?

```
library(spatstat)
library(maptools)
library(lattice)
library(sp)
library(foreign)
require("rgdal")
div0A <- readOGR(dsn="Archive", layer="Projections")
> summary(div0A)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
     min       max
x -80.00 -57.63430
y  66.25  78.16666
Is projected: FALSE
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Data attributes:
       Id      NPAzimutha         UTM20            UTM19           AlberEA      
 Min.   :0   Min.   :348877   Min.   :349232   Min.   :349162   Min.   :348656  
 1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:348877   1st Qu.:349232   1st Qu.:349162   1st Qu.:348656  
 Median :0   Median :348877   Median :349232   Median :349162   Median :348656  
 Mean   :0   Mean   :348877   Mean   :349232   Mean   :349162   Mean   :348656  
 3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:348877   3rd Qu.:349232   3rd Qu.:349162   3rd Qu.:348656  
 Max.   :0   Max.   :348877   Max.   :349232   Max.   :349162   Max.   :348656 

proj4string(div0A) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
xxlcc <- spTransform(div0A, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
res1 <- lapply(slot(xxlcc, "polygons"), function(x)
  sapply(slot(x, "Polygons"), slot, "area"))

> summary(unlist(res1))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
  89.72   89.72   89.72   89.72   89.72   89.72

newW<-as(xxlcc, "owin")
> summary(newW)
Window: polygonal boundary
single connected closed polygon with 29 vertices
enclosing rectangle: [-80, -57.6343]x[66.25, 78.16666]units
Window area =  89.7204 square units
```

Does this look correct? How can I specify/know my unit of length in km?
Moreover, this window is ~Baffin Bay, west of Greenland and I am wondering if I should be using a different datum? E.g. EPSG Projection 4747 - GR96? Although, I will have to create ppp object, for which the coordinates have been taken with GPS satellite navigation system.

I would appreciate if someone can walk me through this or suggest an online example or further readings. I read chapter 4: Spatial Data Import and Export in Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R (2008), but I'm obviously very new to all of this.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Please don't put tags into the thread title. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [geosphere](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/vignettes/geosphere.pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPSG 4326 is a **geographic coordinate system** and as such, has decimal degrees as units of length. If you want meters, you'd need a **projected coordinate system**. That's why you need to do an spTransform. To convert your coordinate system from a geographic to a projected one.

You already had the right commands, if I'm not mistaken. You just need the right projection. Baffin Island should be around [EPSG 2960](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2960/). You might want to check it out. Should work fine once you plug it into spTransform.